# Black Screen appearing in Kivy app despite no errors and warnings

Tags: python, kivy

I am a newbie to Kivy and creating my first project on Kivy which is an image classifier app. I have programmed the entire app but on running the app the app shows a black screen without any errors and warnings.Please help me out

Main.py

```
import numpy as np
import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



class Recognition(BoxLayout):
    img = ObjectProperty(None)
    label = ObjectProperty(None)
    def classify_image(self):
        img_path = self.img.source
        upload_image = image.load_img(img_path,target_size=(210,210),color_mode='rgb')
        upload_image = image.img_to_array(upload_image)
        upload_image = np.expand_dims(upload_image,axis=0)
        my_model = load_model('emotion_model.h5')
        predicted_class = str(my_model.predict_classes(image)[0])
        self.label.text = "Predicted Class: " + predicted_class





class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Recognition()


if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0


<Recogniton>:

    img: img
    label:label

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Predicted Class Appears Here."
            font_size: 30
            id: label
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Image:
                source: "angry.jpg"
                id: img
        Button:
            text: "Classify Image."
            font_size: 30
            on_press: root.classify_image()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo. In your `my.kv`, change:

```
<Recogniton>:
```

to:

```
<Recognition>:
```

Comment: Thank you John 